# Problem with redirecting

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with ASP.NET.

I have button on ex. index.aspx which redirect us to index2.aspx, but before that, first page - index.aspx - was reloaded. I don't need it because function in "load" is running again.

How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a link instead of a button, if you want that the user goes **directly** to the new page.

A button will always cause a *PostBack* and fire the Click event of the button, so you can deal with the user input.

You can also make sure the code in the Load event of the Page is not executed on PostBacks:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // your page initialization code
    }
}
```

But as I said, the proper way to go is a **Link**.